# How do you programmatically access the volume level of a call on iPhone?

Tags: ios, volume, mpvolumeview

Currently, the only way to change the volume of a call is to use the volume buttons on the side of the phone. I find it annoying to have to fiddle around with those buttons when I'm on  a call. I'm trying make something that lets you set an individual caller's voice volume ahead of time. I tried adding some buttons in IB that access the music player's volume property, but that only affected the music volume level. Now, I've implemented an MPVolumeView, but that also seems to only control the music volume. I was under the impression that there was thing called system volume, which includes call volume, that an MPVolumeView could let you manipulate. But apparently it's just for the music volume. Is there any way to access and control call volume programatically(perhaps with MPVolumeView)?